# Removing duplication in horizontal and vertical checks

Tags: c++

```
// Check horizontals
for (int y = 0; y < sGridHeight; y++)
{
    Shape* groupShape = nullptr;
    int groupSize = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < sGridWidth; x++)
    {
        GridItem* gridItem = GetItem(x, y);
        Shape* shape = gridItem->GetShape();
        if (shape == groupShape)
        {
            groupSize++;
            if (groupSize == m_MatchSize)
            {
                g_Audio->PlaySound(m_GemDestroyedSound.c_str());
                m_Score += shape->GetScore();
                for (int tx = x - m_MatchSize + 1; tx <= x; tx++)
                {
                    RANDOMIZE(GetItem(tx, y))
                }
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            groupSize = 1;
            groupShape = shape;
        }
    }
}

// Check verticals
for (int x = 0; x < sGridWidth; x++)
{
    Shape* groupShape = nullptr;
    int groupSize = 0;
    for (int y = 0; y < sGridHeight; y++)
    {
        GridItem* gridItem = GetItem(x, y);
        Shape* shape = gridItem->GetShape();
        if (shape == groupShape)
        {
            groupSize++;
            if (groupSize == m_MatchSize)
            {
                g_Audio->PlaySound(m_GemDestroyedSound.c_str());
                m_Score += shape->GetScore();
                for (int ty = y - m_MatchSize + 1; ty <= y; ty++)
                {
                    RANDOMIZE(GetItem(x, ty))
                }
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            groupSize = 1;
            groupShape = shape;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there an easy way to clean this up? It seems like a lot of code duplication.

I have no qualms about using `#define`s, and I cannot use C++11.

Comment: *I cannot use C++11* - [`nullptr` is in C++11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282295/what-exactly-is-nullptr).

Comment: Good point, I was unclear - I can use C++11, but not the C++11 standard library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most straightforward way to do this is to introduce a new boolean variable `horz` that is true in the case that you wish to check horizontals.  With that simple addition, both routines now can be expressed as one:

```
// if (horz) is true, check horizontals, else check verticals
aLimit = horz ? sGridHeight : sGridWidth;
bLimit = horz ? sGridWidth : sGridHeight;
for (int a = 0; a < aLimit; a++)    
{
    Shape* groupShape = nullptr;
    int groupSize = 0;
    for (int b = 0; b < bLimit; b++)   
    {
        GridItem* gridItem = (horz ? GetItem(b, a) : GetItem(a, b));
        Shape* shape = gridItem->GetShape();  
        if (shape == groupShape)
        {
            groupSize++;
            if (groupSize == m_MatchSize)
            {
                g_Audio->PlaySound(m_GemDestroyedSound.c_str());
                m_Score += shape->GetScore();
                for (int tb = b - m_MatchSize + 1; tb <= b; tb++)  
                {
                    RANDOMIZE(horz ? GetItem(tb, a) : GetItem(a, tb));
                }
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            groupSize = 1;
            groupShape = shape;
        }
    }
}
```

However, there are a number of things that suggest opportunities for further improvement.  In particular, the use of pointers is probably not a good idea.  For example, these two lines:

```
    GridItem* gridItem = (horz ? GetItem(b, a) : GetItem(a, b));
    Shape* shape = gridItem->GetShape();
```

Are the only place that the `gridItem` pointer is used, and it's not checked for `nullptr` before it's dereferenced.  So either that's a bug if `GetItem()` could possibly return a `nullptr` or it should instead be written as a reference.  Even better, it could be combined into a single line and the variable eliminated completely.

Using this modified code is OK, but it's still a little unwieldy, so I would suggest that the `GetItem()` function should take a third argument which is the bool `horz`.  That would make those same two lines of code look like this:

```
    Shape* shape = GetItem(a, b, horz).GetShape();
```

Much nicer, but again, I'd turn this pointer into a reference (or better yet, a `const` reference if possible).

Answer (score 1):

Consider replacing:

```
        groupSize++;
        if (groupSize == m_MatchSize)
        {
            g_Audio->PlaySound(m_GemDestroyedSound.c_str());
            m_Score += shape->GetScore();
            for (int tx = x - m_MatchSize + 1; tx <= x; tx++)
            {
                RANDOMIZE(GetItem(tx, y))
            }
            return;
        }
```

With something more like:

```
groupVector.push_back(gridItem);
if(groupVector.size() == m_MatchSize)
{
    DestroyGroup(groupVector);
    return;
}

// where DestroyGroup looks like:
void MyClass::DestroyGroup(const std::vector<GridItem*> & groupVector)
{
    g_Audio->PlaySound(m_GemDestroyedSound.c_str());
    m_Score += shape->GetScore();
    for(std::vector<GridItem*>::iterator itemIter = groupVector.begin();
        itemIter != groupVector.end();
        ++itemIter)
    {
        RANDOMIZE(*itemIter)
    }
    return;
}
```

I leave optimizing the code above and finding more appropriate function and variable names as an exercise for the original poster. But basically, if you maintain some kind of list of items that you've already traversed you should be able to more easily remove the code duplication that exists between the horizontal and vertical versions of your grid traversal.

Comment: Since the `DestroyGroup` function doesn't care about the positions of any of the `GridItems` it can be used in future algorithms that locate `GridItems` in patterns that aren't vertical or horizontal, such as diagonal, or X-shaped patterns of items.

Comment: And if, in the future, the code starts to use C++11 and eliminate those pointers, the `for` loop gets even cleaner: `for (auto &item : groupvector) RANDOMIZE(item);`